# PHP: Best redirect technique

Tags: php

I'm currently using the excellent mobile detection script from: detectmobilebrowsers.mobi

This works really well however, it redirects every and any page on your main site (including any query parameters) to your mobile site's home page.

What I need is:

http://www.mydomain.com/page.php?var1=X&var2=Y

to direct to:

http://mobile.mydomain.com/page.php?var1=X&var2=Y

I have multiple pages that should redirect with the query string to their mobile versions.

What's the best way to approach this? I thought that I should:

Examine the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] for the page and query string, use a switch/case to loop through the 10 or so pages that I need matching on the main and mobile sites then change the referer URL in the mobile detection script.

Does this make sense?

I've been struggling to get the page and query... any advise and thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($mobile_is_detected) {
    header('Location: http://mobile.mydomain.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Andy, thanks, as always the solution is more simple than I was thinking. I'll just need to add some code to only do this for certain pages. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Andy's answer, when redirecting you should set the response status to 301.

Be careful, you may not call `header()` if you have printed any HTML or `echo`ed anything before calling the function.

```
if ($mobile_is_detected) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://mobile.mydomain.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dimme. Why the need for the 301? I allow the mobile user to choose to go back to the main site if they prefer...

Comment: The 301 is to tell the browser that the web page has moved permanently. It is good for indexing from search engines like Google. It helps you keep your position in Googles rank even after you moved your web page. If you want to give the user the opportunity to go back to the main site then you should probably use `header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily');`

Comment: OK, understood. This script only redirects mobile, the search engines should continue to the main site for indexing...

Comment: Yes but the search engines wont be affected unless they are returning a mobile user agent, which in that case you want them to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to redirect to add the query string to the redirect URL in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but couldn't get the page to display the variables from the referring page. Do I need to change the global settings?